# How to improve embedding process in D-Wave?

Tags: measurement, optimization, d-wave, performance, embedding

I am quite new to the quantum computing field.

Currently, I am trying to solve a combinatorial optimization problem on a D-Wave system, which I successfully translated into QUBO form. I also managed to implement it with the D-Wave Python library.

However, when the solution domain increases, the embedding processing time becomes so large compared to effective QPU access time, that the advantage of solving such a problem with quantum computing disappears. Of course, I tried different embedding approaches provided by D-Wave library. Maybe, I neglected some aspects which can turned into particular values that can be passed as parameters to the sampler. Besides, I also tried using `qbsolv` but I don't see any improvement.

If more information on the problem formulation is needed, I will be glad to provide it. Anyway, I am seeking help or general advices.

Many thanks in advance!